# How to manage the use of global variables to get an smart code

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, global

```
 tableButon = table()
 tableParameter = table()

 entry41 = None
 entry42 = None
 entry43 = None
 entry44 = None
 entry51 = None
 entry52 = None
 entry53 = None
 entry54 = None
 entry61 = None
 entry62 = None
 entry63 = None
 entry64 = None
 entry71 = None
 entry72 = None
 entry73 = None
 entry74 = None
 entry81 = None
 entry82 = None
 entry83 = None
 entry84 = None
 entry91 = None
 entry92 = None
 entry93 = None
 entry94 = None
 entry101 = None
 entry102 = None
 entry104 = None

 entry111 = None
 entry112 = None
 entry113 = None
 entry121 = None
 entry122 = None
 entry123 = None
 entry131 = None
 entry132 = None
 entry141 = None
 entry142 = None
 entry151 = None
 entry152 = None
 entry161 = None
 entry162 = None
 entry171 = None
 entry172 = None

def showParameters(notebook):

     global tablaParametros
     global entry41
     global entry42
     global entry43
     global entry44
     global entry51
     global entry52
     global entry53
     global entry54
     global entry61
     global entry62
     global entry63
     global entry64
     global entry71
     global entry72
     global entry73
     global entry74
     global entry81
     global entry82
     global entry83
     global entry84
     global entry91
     global entry92
     global entry93
     global entry94
     global entry101
     global entry102
     global entry103
     global entry104

     global entry111
     global entry112
     global entry113
     global entry121
     global entry122
     global entry123
     global entry131
     global entry132
     global entry141
     global entry142
     global entry151
     global entry152
     global entry161
     global entry162
     global entry171
     global entry172
     ...........

     entry41 = gnc_plcEntry(plcSymbol="WL_Axial_Cons1", modulo='gnc\gnc_dilataciones.src', plcFactor=1, plcFormat=None, editable=True, sensitive=True, textColor=None, baseColor=None)
     tablaCalculoTemperatura.attachToCell(entry41, col=2, row=2, xpadding=SeparacionH, ypadding=SeparacionV)

     entry42 = gnc_plcEntry(plcSymbol="WL_Axial_Cons2", modulo='gnc\gnc_dilataciones.src', plcFactor=1, plcFormat=None, editable=True, sensitive=True, textColor=None, baseColor=None)
     tablaCalculoTemperatura.attachToCell(entry42, col=3, row=2, xpadding=SeparacionH, ypadding=SeparacionV)
```

....

```
  def updateParameters(notebook):

     global tablaParameter
     global entry41
     global entry42
     ....
     value = jh.Get("\\PLC\\program\\symbol\\module\\'gnc\\gnc_dilataciones.src'\\WL_Axial_Cons1").values()[0]
     entry41.set_text(str(value))
     value = jh.Get("\\PLC\\program\\symbol\\module\\'gnc\\gnc_dilataciones.src'\\WL_Axial_Cons2").values()[0]
     entry42.set_text(str(value))
     .......
```

There are too many global ones and it's a bit tedious to use them this way. I think this is not a good way to handle global variables. Would it be better to use a list with all the global ones? Or maybe make a class and use it with the self? any ideas?

Comment: ... or, not use global variables at all?

Comment: The entries seem sequential, so why not use a list or a tuple with the number as an index?  Alternatively use a single dictionary with the variable names as keys.  You don't show the context you are using these in, but generally it is better to avoid using globals if you can - it breaks encapsulation principles.

Comment: 1: Use a `list` of it's a sequential order 2: If you want to store them by accessing them with a name or a key, use a `dict` for instance: `x = {'entry1' : None, 'entry2' : None, ...}`

Comment: @DanielRoseman How can I manage the variables to update the entries of an interface, to refer to them? If it did not use globals it had errors

Comment: That's impossible to answer without seeing your actual code. What are you doing with all those globals? Where do you need to access them? What "interface" is this?

Comment: @cdarke I use it to update the entries of an interface, reading the new value externally. So I need to have a reference to update the exact entry. The entrys are plcEntry type.

Comment: I'm going to do tests with @Torxed solution. thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would to not use so many different lists.
You should rather use one list (sequential order) or use a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['entry1'] = None
my_dict['entry2'] = None
...

def my_func():
    global my_dict
    print(my_dict)
```

But I would also recommend you pass the dict as a parameter rather than trying to globalize it.

```
def my_func(d):
    print(d)
my_func(my_dict)
```

You could also just create a loop to create the numerous variables if they're all going to contain `None`.

```
for i in range(0,1000):
    my_dict['entry'+str(i)] = None
```

Comment: Thank you I will use your solution, it seems claner than mine.